# Multithreaded Java applet bouncing balls

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I'm trying to create a Java applet that bounces several balls within an applet window, each with its own thread. With the code below all the balls are drawn, but only the first one moves. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import static java.awt.Color.*;

public class BouncingBalls extends Applet implements Runnable {

    List<Ball> ballList = new ArrayList(); // holds Ball objects

    Color[] colors = new Color[]{BLACK, GRAY, WHITE, PINK, RED, ORANGE, YELLOW,
            GREEN, BLUE, CYAN}; // array holding available colors

    static int width, height; // variables for applet dimensions

    int ballCount; // number of balls to be created, set by html parameter

    Random random = new Random(); // random number generator


    public void init() {

        // get window dimensions
        width = getSize().width;
        height = getSize().height;

        //get number of balls from html
        String ballCountString = this.getParameter("ballCount");

        try {
            ballCount = Integer.parseInt(ballCountString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ballCount = 10; // set to 10 by default
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ballCount; i++) {

            // randomly assign ballDiameter between 1 and 20
            int ballDiameter = random.nextInt(20) + 1;

            // create and add balls to ballList
            ballList.add(new Ball(
                    random.nextInt(width - ballDiameter), // set x coordinate
                    random.nextInt(height - ballDiameter), // set y coordinate
                    ballDiameter, // set ballDiameter
                    random.nextInt(ballDiameter) + 1, // deltaX <= ballDiameter
                    random.nextInt(ballDiameter) + 1, // deltaY <= ballDiameter
                    colors[i % 10] // use remainder to choose colors[] element
                    )
            );

        } // end for

    } // end init


    public void start() {

        for (Ball ball: ballList) {

            Thread t;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();

        } // end for

    } // end start


    public void run() {

        for (Ball ball : ballList) {

            // infinite loop: ball moves until applet is closed
            while (true) {

                ball.move();

                repaint(); // call paint method to draw circle in new location

                // set ball repaint delay using Thread sleep method
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20); // wait 20 msec before continuing
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }

            } // end while

        } // end for

    } // end run

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        for (Ball ball : ballList) {

            // set current color
            g.setColor(ball.ballColor);

            // draw filled oval using current x and y coordinates and diameter
            g.fillOval(ball.x, ball.y, ball.diameter, ball.diameter);

        } // end for

    } // end paint
}

class Ball {

    int x, y, // coordinates of upper-left corner of circle
        diameter, // circle diameter
        deltaX, deltaY; // number of pixels ball moves each time it's repainted
    Color ballColor;


    public Ball(int x, int y, int diameter, int deltaX, int deltaY,
                Color ballColor) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.deltaX = deltaX;
        this.deltaY = deltaY;
        this.ballColor = ballColor;

    } // end Ball constructor


    public void move() {

        // update x and y coordinates using delta values
        x += deltaX;
        y += deltaY;

        // reverse x direction when ball reaches boundary
        if (x >= BouncingBalls.width - diameter || x <= 0){
            deltaX = -deltaX;
        } // end if

        // reverse y direction when ball reaches boundary
        if (y >= BouncingBalls.height - diameter || y <= 0) {
            deltaY = -deltaY;
        } // end if

    } // end move

} // end BouncingBalls
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `while(true)` should be outside the for loop.  It sits on the first ball returned from the iterator.

That being said, you may want to go over your logic for one ball-per-thread.  It actually appears to create N number of threads (N being the number of balls) in which each thread will move all the balls instead of just one.

Edit to address my second point:

Let's say you have 10 balls.  You start 10 threads, and each thread iterates over all balls.

For instance:

```
Thread 1:
public void run(){
   for(Ball b : ballList){
      b.move();
      b.repaint();
   }
}

Thread 2:
public void run(){
   for(Ball b : ballList){
      b.move();
      b.repaint();
   }
}

Thread N:
public void run(){
   for(Ball b : ballList){
      b.move();
      b.repaint();
   }
}
```

This is done because you create threads with the same `this` instance of a runnable that iterates over each ball.

```
 public void start() {

        for (Ball ball: ballList) {

            Thread t;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();

        } // end for

    } // end start
```

So I would think, if each ball is supposed to move 1 unit every 20 milliseconds.  You should end up seeing every 20 milliseconds moving N*1 units in this case 10 every 20 milliseconds.

Edit - With regards to a suggestion.

Instead of setting `this` as the runnable you should remove the implementation of Runnable from the `this` class and create a new Runnable that will take a single Ball as a parameter.

```
private static class MovingRunnable implements Runnable{
   private final Ball b;
   private MovingRunnable(Ball b){this.b=b;}
   public void run(){
      for(;;){
         b.move(); 
         b.repaint();
         Thread.sleep(20);
      }
   }
}
```

**Later in your start method**

```
public void start() {
        for (Ball ball: ballList) {
            Thread t;
            t = new Thread(new MovingRunnable(ball));
            t.start();
        } // end for

    } // end start
```

So here each Ball has it's own thread with it's own Runnable.  Each ball will now only invoke `move` once per thread every 20 milliseconds.

But it still isn't perfect because `repaint` should only be invoked by the UI thread, having it invoked by each thread can cause different issues (though you may not notice any, it's just worth saying).

Comment: Thanks a million, John. Swapping the while and for fixed it. Although I don't think I follow how each thread moves all the balls.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to have the Ball class extend Thread (or implement Runnable) so that each runs as its own thread?

Comment: Thanks again, John. I'm relatively new to Java (and coding in general). It seems that I often reach the point of diminishing returns, where after working on a problem for hours and days I can't figure out things that seem simple and obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @ChrisDevo Yea I understand, we've all been there.  That being said, multithreaded programming is very difficult so keep it at least in perspective :).